# PHP foreach loop insert into PHP variable

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, email, html-email

I need some help constructing the proper structure for an HTML email that I am trying to send using PHP.  Here is the line which sends the email:

```
$this->_send_user_email($recipient, $subject, $message);
```

Where I am having trouble is constructing the `$message`.  I need the `$message` to include a table with a dynamic number of rows.  Here is the current structure of the `$message` variable:

```
$message = "Hello, <br><br> 
Please review details in the table below:
<br><br>
**** NEED TO INSERT DYNAMIC PHP TABLE HERE ****
<br><br>
If you have questions, please call 1-888-888-8888 and we will assist you.
<br><br>
Customer Support<br> 
<br><br>
";
```

I am unsure of how to insert my PHP foreach loop inside this existing `$messsage` variable.  I get confused about when to close the quotes and how to continue etc.  Here is the code for the foreach loop that I am trying to insert:

```
<?php if (is_array($foo['bar'])):  ?>    
<table>
    <tr>
        <th >1</th>
        <th >2</th>
        <th >3</th>
    </tr>
<?php $row = 01; 
foreach ($foo['bar'] as $key => $value): ?>
<tr>
    <td ><?php echo str_pad($row++, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?></td>
    <td >AAA</td>
    <td >BBB</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So I guess my question is:  What is the correct way to insert this PHP foreach loop into the `$message` variable above?

Comment: Additionally to following some of the advice in the given answers, you should really try to completely take your markup (HTML) and your PHP apart from each other!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way of doing this is splitting the template message in two strings say $message1 and $message2 where the first contains everything up until the dynamic table and the latter everything that starts after the table. Then you generate your dynamic table with string concatenation and you concatenate the three parts of the whole message.

```
$message1 = "Hello, <br><br> 
Please review details in the table below:
<br><br>";

$message2 = "<br><br>
If you have questions, please call 1-888-888-8888 and we will assist you.
<br><br>
Customer Support<br> 
<br><br>";

$row = "01";

$table = "";

if(is_array($foo['bar'])) {   

    $table .= "<table>
                <tr>
                    <th >1</th>
                    <th >2</th>
                    <th >3</th>
                </tr>"; 

    foreach($foo['bar'] as $key => $value) {
        $table .= "<tr>
                     <td >" . str_pad($row++, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "</td>
                     <td >AAA</td>
                     <td >BBB</td>
                   </tr>";
    }

    $table .= "</table>";
}

$message = $message1 . $table. $message2;
```

Now as someone mentioned in the comments, this code will work but is quite messy, in the sense that you heavily mix php logic and plain html text. Ideally you want to separate these two as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful explanation.  I'm going to give this a shot when I get home.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: what do you mean by "generate your dynamic table with string concatenation"?

Answer (score 1):

You are able to create a static HTML message using php that is sent to your user, however you can NOT include php within your email(if that's what you're trying to do) so that the email is dynamic as it is displayed.  So assuming you're doing the former, the code in joe42s answer is spot on.  he's written if for you!

if you want a dynamically updated email that changes when people look at it (using php), you could generate a link to be sent in the email with parameters in it that would display a webpage customized for the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <?php 
            $message = "Hello, <br><br> 
            Please review details in the table below:
            <br><br>";

            if (is_array($foo['bar'])) {  
                $message .= "<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th >1</th>
                        <th >2</th>
                        <th >3</th>
                    </tr>";

                $row = 01; 
                foreach ($foo['bar'] as $key => $value) {
                    $message .= "<tr>
                        <td >".str_pad($row++, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)."</td>
                        <td >AAA</td>
                        <td >BBB</td>
                    </tr>";
                }
                $message .= "</table>";
            }

            $message .= "<br><br>
            If you have any questions, please call 1-888-888-8888 and we will be happy to assist you.
            <br><br>
            Customer Support<br> 
            <br><br>
            ";  
            ?>
```

Comment: Thanks joe42, this looks great.  I'm going to give this a shot when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your way may work some way or another but i may advice with more proper way to send an email 
you can use view as message content, for example :

```
$data=$foo;
$message = $this->load->view('some view',$data,true);
```

and you can deal with it as normal view

Comment: You should really be passing `$foo` as an array element of `$data`, like so: `$data = array('foo' => $foo);` otherwise you will create a new variable for every index in `$foo`, opposed to just creating one variable called `$foo` in your view file.